# FizzBuzz quiz in js array

Tags: javascript, fizzbuzz

Trying to write a fizzBuzz quiz to generate the word `"fizz"` for any number in an array divisible by 5, and the word `"Buzz"` for number  divisible by  3 and lastly `"fizzBuzz"` for number divisible by 5 and 3 using the chrome JavaScript console.

This code just prints the numbers without replacing them with the word fizz and Buzz.

I'm expected to keep entering the function `fizzBuzz()` in the console, so as to keep generating other numbers, my question is, why isn't working?.

I expected result like:

```js
[1,2,"Buzz",4,"Fizz","Buzz",7,8,"Buzz","Fizz",11,"Buzz",13,14,"FizzBuzz"]
```

But instead I get:

```js
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
```

This is my current code:

```js
var output=[];
var previous = 1;
function fizzBuzz(){
    if (output[(previous-1)]%5===0 && output[(previous-1)]%3===0){
        output.push(("FizzBuzz"));
        console.log(output);
        previous++;
    }
    else if (output[(previous-1)]%5===0){
         output.push("Fizz");
        console.log(output);
        previous++;
        
    }
    else if (output[(previous-1)]%3===0){
         output.push("Buzz");
        console.log(output);
        previous++;
    }
    else {
        output.push(previous);
        console.log(output);
        previous++;
        
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: You're making it way too complicated than it should be. Just check the value by itself: `previous%5===0` etc.

Comment: Add some *basic* debugging - check the value of `output[(previous-1)]` as the first value of the function (ie `function fizzBuzz() { console.log(output[(previous-1)]); ...`).   That will give you your answer.

Comment: which is that the output[] array is empty when you first run, so output[1-1] hasn't been set yet, so you're %5 nothing.

Answer (score 1):

So after checking your advices i change my algorithm and this one works,

```
var output = []
var previous = 1
function fizzBuzz(){
    if (previous % 5 === 0 && previous % 3 === 0){
        output.push(("FizzBuzz"));
        console.log(output);
        previous++;
    }
    else if (previous  % 5 === 0){
         output.push("Fizz");
        console.log(output);
        previous++;
        
    }
    else if (previous % 3 === 0){
         output.push("Buzz");
        console.log(output);
        previous++;
    }
    else {
        output.push(previous);
        console.log(output);
        previous++;
        
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: Next: use `yield` and remove the need for `previous` :)

Answer (score 1):

An easier approach to achieve the same result without declaring additional variables is by mutating the original array.

```
function fizzBuzz(array) {
  array.forEach((element, index) => {
    if (element % 5 === 0 && element % 3 === 0) {
      array[index] = 'FizzBuzz';
    } else if (element % 5 === 0) {
      array[index] = 'Fizz';
    } else if (element % 3 === 0) {
      array[index] = 'Buzz';
    }
  });

  return array;
}
```

Comment: Note: the "original array" was: `var output=[];`.

Comment: Also: you can do `array[element] = '...'` - no need for splice, arrays aren't immutable.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a generator function instead of keeping global variables! For instance

```js
function* fizzBuzz(length = 15) {
  for (let i = 1; i <= length; i++) {
    let value = i;
    if (i % 15 === 0) {
      value = 'FizzBuzz';
    } else if (i % 5 === 0) {
      value = 'Fizz';
    } else if (i % 3 === 0) {
      value = 'Buzz';
    }
    yield value;
  }
}

for (const i of fizzBuzz()) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

or maybe a closure that behaves like a generator

```js
const fizzBuzz = (function(length = 15) {
  const result = Array.from({
    length
  }, (_, i) => {
    if ((i + 1) % 15 === 0) {
      return 'FizzBuzz';
    } else if ((i + 1) % 5 === 0) {
      return 'Fizz';
    } else if ((i + 1) % 3 === 0) {
      return 'Buzz';
    }
    return (i + 1);
  });
  let index = 0;

  return () => {
    if (index >= length) {
      index = 0;
    }
    return result[index++];
  };
})();

console.log(fizzBuzz());
console.log(fizzBuzz());
console.log(fizzBuzz());
console.log(fizzBuzz());
console.log(fizzBuzz());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this out :D

```js
function fizzBuzz (){
    const arr = Array.from({length: 15}, (v, i) => i + 1).map((v) => v = (v % 3 == 0 ?  "Fizz" : "") + (v % 5 == 0 ? "Buzz" : "") || v)
    console.log(arr)
}
fizzBuzz()
```